# Keras' model evaluate expecting training set dimensions instead of test set dimensions

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I currently have a simple LSTM model implemented in Keras, with a training set x_train of dimensions (1,18227, 98) and a test set x_test of dimensions (1,3217, 98) timesteps/features, respectively. Currently the model is training without hitch, but when I attempt to evaluate using my test set, I receive this error:

```
    File "keras_LSTM.py", line 170, in <module>
        loss, f1, precision = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, 
    batch_size=batch_size)
      File 
    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1102, in evaluate
        batch_size=batch_size)
      File 
    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 751, in _standardize_user_data
        exception_prefix='input')
      File 
    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site- 
   packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 138, in 
    standardize_input_data
        str(data_shape))
    ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 
    shape (18227, 98) but got array with shape (3217, 98)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - will provide code if needed. It should also be noted that my input shapes are 3 dimensional - however the error report omits the batch_size dimension and output a tuple of (sequence_length, feature_number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ankish Bansal's idea of splitting the long sequence in small windows may be a good approach. But you might want to keep the entire sequence connected for some reason.

In that case, you should set your `input_shape=(None,98)`, this way, your model accepts any sequence length. (Provided you don't use any  `Flatten` layer or others that require fixed dimensions.)

But, if there is "more than one sequence" in your data, you should probably review everything, because the number of sequences usually should be the batch size.

Answer (score 2):

Keras LSTM layer expects the input to be 3 dims as (batch_size, seq_length, input_dims), but you have assigned it wrongly. Try this

First reshape your data as:
 (1,18227, 98) and a test set x_test of dimensions (1,3217, 98)

```
X_train = x_train.reshape(-1,98)
X_test = x_test.reshape(-1,98)
```

Now, use choose `seq_length`, i chose 10.

```
seq_length = 10
X_train1 = []
X_test1 = []
for i in range(0, X_train.shape[0] - seq_length, 1):
    X_train1.append(X_train[i:i+seq_length])      
    X_test1.append(X_test[i:i+seq_length])
    # labels.append(labels[i+seq_length-1])
import numpy as np
X_train1 = np.reshape(X_train1, (-1, seq_length, 98))
X_test1 = np.reshape(X_test1, (-1, seq_length, 98))
```

Now, you are good to go

```
input_dims = 98 # an integer
seq_length = 10 # an integer
model = Sequential()
 model.add(LSTM(128, activation='relu', input_shape=(seq_length, input_dims), return_sequences=True))
```

You were using single sequence, for your model, which is ineffective way.